# Style defined in resourcedictionary doesn't set TextBox VerticalContentAlignment properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The issue I am facing now is that after defining a style for the textbox in the Resource Dictionary the VerticalContentAlignment of the text being typed into the textbox always stays at top. I want it to be center aligned at all times. I am not overriding the `VerticalContentAlignment` property while defining the textbox. I also tried setting the `VerticalContentAlignment` property while creating a textbox and tried setting it to `Center` but of no use.

Could you please help me figure out what I am doing wrong which causes the text to be aligned vertically to top instead of center at all times. Please see below image :

[image]

Please see the style code I have defined for the TextBox, below.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FA092464" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#80D7D8D8" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="CaretBrush" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="32" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst" />
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border x:Name="border"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  Focusable="false"
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.56" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFD7D8D8" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFD7D8D8" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true" />
                <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="Orange" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied this `Style` as is and used it. The result was blue text box with alignment to center text, whereas according to you screenshot your text box has white background, that means your text box uses another `Style`.
If this `Style` located in some resource dictionary, it is possible that somewhere in resources exists another Text box style without key that overrides `Style` without `Key` you want to be applied. 
To verify my suppose, add to your `Style` some `Key` like `x:Key="MyStyleTextBox"` and apply to your TextBox :

```
<TextBox Text="Text Box text" Style={StaticResource MyStyleTextBox}"></TextBox>
```